# Embed Page Without iFrame

Tags: php, html

This may not be possible, but I am looking for a different way to include a full page inside a PHP page. Currently the method I am using is an iframe. For certain reasons we want to move away from the iframed approach and look into alternate methods. The problem is, the iframe provided a nice self-contained environment for the child page.

PHP includes are not viable because the whole path structure is changed on the child when you include it into the parent page, and css/javascript from the parent now effect the child and vice versa. The child contains full html structure and including that directly inside another page will cause all sorts of wackiness. We also have almost 2000 of these child pages that vary in design, so it's nothing that could be changed with an automated script. Needless to say we don't want to have to touch the child pages.

So my question, is there any way to include a page into another page without using an iframe, while still preserving the child's path structure and not have the two pages conflict with each other (in regards to code/styles/scripts on each). Any tips would help.

Comment: There's no automated way to make it so that the two pages won't conflict with each other if you just try to include/require them. From what it sounds like you are trying to do templating, and whoever made the initial site really botched the idea of templating up. If you don't want to use iframes then you're going to have to manually take out / change any problems. You could potentially write a script to do this.

Comment: What is wrong with an iframe?

Comment: There's many little problems with iframes in mobile browsing that we've experienced, and W3C seems to want to dump them so there's an uncertain future.

Comment: I'd be astonished if any other technique had fewer issues than iframes, and the W3C have given up on trying to get rid of them as of several years ago when they adopted WHATWG's HTML 5 work.

Comment: OK, I was pretty sure of this but I didn't want to rule out any new tools/methods I might be unaware of. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ajax and reset style in the child. Example:

```
<div id="ajax_container">
    .. Content Loaded by Ajax ..
</div>

div#ajax_container * {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: none;
    ...
    font-family: Arial;
}
```

Comment: The problem still exists that the content loaded by the ajax would be an entire html page (complete with doctype, html, head, body tags etc). Throwing that inside a div would not turn out good. Then there's also the path of elements (images, css, js) in the child would now be referenced from the parent page and would break.

Comment: Okay, I didn't know that. Mhmm, other than that, there's pretty much no other way I think ...